# Is claiming $0 in withholding deductions on 2020 W-4 the same as claiming 0 allowances in the past?

Tags: united-states, form-w-4

The [IRS form W-4 for 2020](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf) has you compute any amount that should be deducted from your federal income tax withholdings and then report the amount in dollars. In the past I merely reported the number of allowances that I was claiming.

I've recently changed employers, and am wondering if for 2020 I do none of the calculations and just write $0 in each spot of the 2020 W-4, will this have the same effect as claiming 0 allowances in the past?

Comment: The answer is likely NO, though I am not sure how many situations that applies to.   As far as I can tell, no way of filling out 2020 W4 is equivalent to the 2019 W4.  You can play with the simple [IRS withholding calculator](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/income-tax-withholding-assistant-for-employers)... what you would need to do to achieve equal withholding is fill it out like pre-2020 and then adjust the 2020 numbers to match.